# How to write a custom rule in SQLFluff?

Tags: lint, sqlfluff

I was learning about SQLFluff and how to lint using it. While linting, it used only the default rules for checking. But our product need different customised rules for linting. So, I planned to write a custom rule in SQLFluff.

I was trying to find how a custom rule is written. But was not able find it. I need the step wise procedure to write a custom rule in SQLFluff.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a thorough explanation of the various function methods to develop custom rules [here](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/developingrules.html).

The text can be dense. So to look at examples, you can look directly at the [code for the build-in rules themselves](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/tree/main/src/sqlfluff/rules). Clicking on the [`capitalisation/`](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/tree/main/src/sqlfluff/rules/capitalisation) directory, you can see the different rules on capitalisation `CP{01,02,03,04,05}`.